# How to provide secure flag (HTTPS-only) for session cookie in Rails application be accessed over secure SSL channels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, https, session-cookies, passenger

I am using :active_record_store for session_store in Rails 4.1.1 application. 
I need to make session cookie secure (HTTPS only) in my application. 
Tried below code in development enviroment, but did not work for me.

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :session_store, key: '_session_id', secure: true

config.force_ssl = true: makes all cookie(s) as secure whcih is not  requirement.
```

How can I set Secure flag for cookie by default in application configuration so that it instructs the browser that the cookie can only be accessed over secure SSL channels?

Comment: What is `:session_store`?

Comment: @Khaja Bhanu Mohd Did u find the configuration to be put

Answer (score 1):

To flag the session cookie as secure you can do this,

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store,
  key: "_session_id",
  secret: "your_secret",
  secure: Rails.env.development?,
  httponly: true
```

> config.session_store is usually set up in
>   config/initializers/session_store.rb and specifies what class to use
>   to store the session. Possible values are :cookie_store which is the
>   default, :mem_cache_store, and :disabled. The last one tells Rails not
>   to deal with sessions.

Comment: This answer did not help because we use :session_store for  sessions.